# Search into a table using the foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am am trying to get the value of a table that has a relationship with another table, but I don't know how I could do my query to get the correct result.

example:

This is my db schema:

[image]

I want make my query using email attribute (Employeees table) and obtain the PTO columns.

I'm trying to use:

```
Select *
from dbo.PTO, dbo.Employee
WHERE employee_cedula = (select cedula
                         from dbo.Employee
                         WHERE email = 'reco@hotmail.com');
```

and

```
from dbo.PTO
INNER Join dbo.Employee
on dbo.PTO.employee_cedula = (select cedula
                             from dbo.Employee
                             WHERE email = 'reco@hotmail');
```

But this returns all rows from the PTO table

Answer (score 0):

Go with this.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.PTO a
INNER JOIN dbo.Employee b on a.employee_cedula = b.cedula
WHERE email = 'reco@hotmail';
```

Comment: when suggesting edits please be sure to correct all the issues.